EGARCH model with low R-squared and negative log-likelihood
I am not very experienced with coding and have been working on a model I found on GitHub to estimate the volatility of the S&P 500. The code implements an EGARCH(1,1) model, but I noticed that the R-squared is quite low, and the log-likelihood is highly negative, which indicates that the model isn't performing well.
I was wondering if anyone could help improve the model or provide suggestions to make it more functional. Specifically, I’d appreciate if someone could share a more robust implementation or modifications to improve the model's performance metrics.
Here’s a brief summary of the issue:
Dataset: S&P 500 daily returns and VIX data.
Problem: Low R-squared and very negative log-likelihood.
Goal: Enhance the model’s explanatory power and forecasting accuracy.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
from arch import arch_model
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Download S&P 500 and VIX data from Yahoo Finance
sp500 = yf.download('^GSPC', start='2000-01-01', end='2021-09-01', progress=False)
vix = yf.download('^VIX', start='2000-01-01', end='2021-09-01', progress=False)

# Calculate daily returns for S&P 500 index
sp500['SP500_Returns'] = 100 * sp500['Adj Close'].pct_change().dropna()

# Calculate realized variance (squared returns)
sp500['Realized_Variance'] = sp500['SP500_Returns']**2

# Merge S&P 500 returns and VIX data
# Change to merging on Date column of vix, instead of index. Reset index of vix to get Date column.
data = pd.merge(sp500, vix.reset_index()[['Date', 'Adj Close']], on='Date', how='inner')
data.columns = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume', 'SP500_Returns', 'Realized_Variance', 'VIX']

# Imposta 'Date' come indice
data = data.set_index('Date')

# data['VIX'] = data['VIX'].shift(1)  # Use lagged VIX
data = data.dropna()
data['VIX'] = data["VIX"]**2

# Fit the EGARCH(1,1) model
egarch_model = arch_model(data['SP500_Returns'], vol='EGARCH', p=1, q=1)
egarch_results = egarch_model.fit()

# Obtain EGARCH variance estimates
data['EGARCH_Variance'] = egarch_results.conditional_volatility**2

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_data = data.iloc[:-150]  # Use all data except the last 252 days (approximately one year) for training
test_data = data.iloc[-150:]   # Use the last 252 days for testing

# Model 1: Realized variance vs EGARCH variance
X1_train = train_data[['EGARCH_Variance']]
X1_train = sm.add_constant(X1_train)
y_train = train_data['Realized_Variance']

model1 = sm.OLS(y_train, X1_train)
results1 = model1.fit()

# Model 2: Realized variance vs EGARCH variance and VIX level
X2_train = train_data[['EGARCH_Variance', 'VIX']]
X2_train = sm.add_constant(X2_train)

model2 = sm.OLS(y_train, X2_train)
results2 = model2.fit()

# Out-of-sample forecasts
X1_test = test_data[['EGARCH_Variance']]
X1_test = sm.add_constant(X1_test)
y_test = test_data['Realized_Variance']

X2_test = test_data[['EGARCH_Variance', 'VIX']]
X2_test = sm.add_constant(X2_test)

y_pred_model1 = results1.predict(X1_test)
y_pred_model2 = results2.predict(X2_test)

# Plot the out-of-sample forecasts against the actual realized variance
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(test_data.index, y_test, label="Realized Variance", linewidth=2, color="black", alpha=0.7)
plt.plot(test_data.index, y_pred_model1, label="Model 1 (EGARCH Variance)", linestyle="--", linewidth=2, color="red")
plt.plot(test_data.index, y_pred_model2, label="Model 2 (EGARCH Variance + VIX)", linestyle=":", linewidth=2, color="blue")

plt.ylabel("Variance")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Out-of-Sample Forecasts vs Actual Realized Variance")
plt.show()


Where in the code do you obtain $R^2$ and log-likelihood? (I am not a Python user, so it is not obvious to me where that happens.) I see your code contains references to realized variance. When you are concerned with low $R^2$, is this the "usual" $R^2$ (the squared correlation between observations and fitted values) or the squared correlation between fitted variance and some measure of actual variance (like realized variance)?
